# Why I am unable to display database values in jsp page , using spring mvc and hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

Any one can help me...?? Actually I am unable to display my database values in the jsp page...! Here I am sharing all my code...!! Please find it and help me....I am doing well. actually it not gives any error. so i am too much confuse. so anyone can help me...Please. Thank You.

My Dao Class is look as

```
package com.mvn.blog.dao;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.mvn.blog.domain.UserDomain;
import com.mvn.blog.dto.UserDto;
import com.mvn.blog.utility.CommonUtils;

@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements IUserDao {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf) {
          this.sessionFactory = sf;

    }

    @Transactional
    public Boolean saveUser(UserDto userDto) throws Exception {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        boolean result= false;
        UserDomain user = CommonUtils.convertObject(userDto, UserDomain.class);

        session.save(user);
        result = true;
        return result;
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<UserDto> getUserList() throws Exception {
        List<UserDto> userList = new ArrayList<UserDto>();
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Criteria user = session.createCriteria(UserDomain.class);

        List<UserDomain> result = user.list();
        //System.out.println(result);
        for(UserDomain userDomain : result){
            UserDto userDto = CommonUtils.convertObject(userDomain, UserDto.class);
            userList.add(userDto);      
            }
        //System.out.println(userList);

        return userList;
    }

    }

}
```

My controllerClass

```
package com.mvn.blog.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.mvn.blog.domain.UserDomain;
import com.mvn.blog.dto.UserDto;
import com.mvn.blog.service.IUserMaintenance;
import com.mvn.blog.utility.CommonUtils;

@Controller
public class HomeController {


    @Autowired
    IUserMaintenance userMaintenance;


    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home(){
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/userlist" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView  getUserList() throws Exception{
        List<UserDto> userList = userMaintenance.getUserList();
        //System.out.println(userList);

        for(UserDto users : userList){
            System.out.println(users.getUsername()+" "+ users.getEmail()+" "+users.getPassword());

        }

        return new  ModelAndView("viewuser", "userList" , userList);
}

}





My Jsp File


<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%> 
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>   
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<body>
<h2>User List</h2>  
<table border="2">  
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Password</th><th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th></tr>  
   <c:forEach items="${userList}" var="user">   
   <tr>  
   <td><c:out value="${user.username}"/></td>  
   <td><c:out value="${user.email}"/></td>  
   <td><c:out value="${user.password}"/></td>  
   <td><a href="edituser/${user.userid}">Edit</a></td>  
   <td><a href="deleteuser/${user.userid}">Delete</a></td>  
   </tr>  
   </c:forEach>  
   </table>  
   <br/> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank You sir, for responding me. but it also not working...if any suggestion...so please..help!!

Comment: your controller print `list` ? also try to check if `userList` empty or not in jsp i.e. `${empty userList}`

Comment: Yes sir...userList is empty in jsp page..I am trying it as like..<c:if test="${empty userList}">....but sir data is comming from database in my controller class...I printed it in console..it works...but sir why it is not reachable in jsp page...please sir help me.....Thank You.!!!

Comment: how can i fix these errors...please help

Comment: here is my userDto Class

Comment: here is my userDto Class----public class UserDto {
    private Long userid;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;---->>after that getter and setter methods and constructor  are generated..you can see on My Whole userDto.class in my answer...which is given bellow...Thank You. for giving me your time...!!!

Comment: try to put `<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>` in jsp's `<head>` tag

Comment: don't put code in answer rather put in question, also show `web.xml`

Comment: ok...It is Web.xml file thank You......<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
 
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
 <servlet>
     <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>
      org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
     </servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

Comment: Oh!....sir finally its working while I use <%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>  it...can You explain why it is working now..?? Thank You so much sir...to give me your precious time....Sir can I touch with you..?? can you share your email id with me....???..Please.!!

Answer (score 0):

This is bcoz you are using the old JSP 1.2 descriptor, defined by DTD.
The EL is disabled or ignored by default, you have to enable it manually.
use the standard JSP 2.0 or above descriptor, defined by w3c schema.

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
/...
</web-app>
```

Have a look at this [reference](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/modelandviews-model-value-is-not-displayed-in-jsp-via-el/)

Comment: Thank You sir...It's Working..!!